# How can I add ESLInt custom rules directory to VSCode

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, eslintrc

I am running VSCode with the ESLint plugin. My project contains some custom rules, which live in a particular directory.

If I run ESLint from the command line and pass in `--rulesdir=./custom-eslint-rules` everything works as expected.

However, I am specifically referring to the linting that happens *per file* in the editor itself. There, it lints using the normal rules, but shows errors that the definitions for my custom rules are missing.

How can I configure VSCode so that the per-file linting sees my custom rule definitions that live in a particular directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your setting.json:

```
"eslint.options": {
  "rulePaths": "<path>"
}
```

Reference: https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#cliengine

Comment: `rulePaths` value should be an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

## Write your own eslint plugin and use it with vs code compatibility

‌

#### 1. install `eslint-plugin-rulesdir@0.2.1`

```
yarn add --dev eslint-plugin-rulesdir@0.2.1
```

#### 2. add to .eslintrc.js

##### import

```
const rulesDirPlugin = require("eslint-plugin-rulesdir");
rulesDirPlugin.RULES_DIR = "src/rules"; // it is example
```

##### plugins

```
plugins: [...,"rulesdir"]
```

##### rules

```
rules: {
  ...,
  "rulesdir/no-get-payments": "error"
}
```

#### 3. create rule file src/rules/no-get-payments.js

```
module.exports = {
  create: function (context) {
    return {
      CallExpression: function (node) {
        if (node.callee.name === "getPayments") {
          context.report({
            node: node,
            message: "getPayments is depricated! ",
          });
        }
      },
    };
  },
};
```

‌